# append a new line in a nested for loop in Python

Tags: python, newline, nested-for-loop

I want to change the color of the letters in a list of words. I use colorama library.
Code:

```
from colorama import Fore
guess = ['great', 'hello', 'brave', 'stone']
li,ly = [],[]
for word in guess:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == 'b' or word[i] == 'a':
            color = Fore.RED
        elif word[i] == 's' or word[i] == 'e':
            color = Fore.GREEN
        else:
            color = Fore.BLACK
        letter = color + word[i] + Fore.RESET
        li.append(letter)
    result = ' '.join(li)
    ly.append(result)
print(*ly, sep = '\n')
```

Output is

g r e a t

g r e a t h e l l o

g r e a t h e l l o b r a v e

g r e a t h e l l o b r a v e s t o n e

Desired output would be

```
g r e a t

g r e a t

h e l l o

g r e a t

h e l l o 

b r a v e

g r e a t 

h e l l o 

b r a v e 

s t o n e
```

How do I add a new line in a nested for loop? I have not found a solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
guess = ['great', 'hello', 'brave', 'stone']
color_letters = []
spaced_words = []

for word in guess:
    # insert spaces between letters
    for letter in ' '.join(word):

        # identify colour to apply
        if letter in 'ab':
            color = Fore.RED
        elif letter in 'es':
            color = Fore.GREEN
        else:
            color = Fore.BLACK

        # append to cumulative list of formatted letters
        color_letters.append(color + letter + Fore.RESET)

    # insert line breaks between words
    color_letters += '\n\n'

    # add / re-add cumulative list of letters to output list
    spaced_words.append(''.join(color_letters))

print(''.join(spaced_words))
```

Comment: Yep, it is working. thank you. And your 'in' is way better than my or condition.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Not sure if this is the exact solution you are looking for, but I was able to print them like this by appending a "\n"

```py
from colorama import Fore
guess = ['great', 'hello', 'brave', 'stone']
li,ly = [],[]
for word in guess:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == 'b' or word[i] == 'a':
            color = Fore.RED
        elif word[i] == 's' or word[i] == 'e':
            color = Fore.GREEN
        else:
            color = Fore.BLACK
        letter = color + word[i] + Fore.RESET
        li.append(letter)
    li.append("\n")
    result = ''.join(li)
    ly.append(result.rstrip())
    
print(*ly, sep = '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `li` contains the words without newlines and is not cleared after each iteration, resulting in missing newlines.

A solution would be to clear `li` after each iteration:

```py
from colorama import Fore
guess = ['great', 'hello', 'brave', 'stone']
text, line = [], []
for word in guess:
    for character in word:
        if character == 'b' or character == 'a':
            color = Fore.RED
        elif character == 's' or character == 'e':
            color = Fore.GREEN
        else:
            color = Fore.BLACK
        line.append(color + character + Fore.RESET)
    text.append(' '.join(line))
    line.clear()
print(*text, sep = '\n')
```

If you want the repetitions then create them with a loop:

```py
from colorama import Fore
guess = ['great', 'hello', 'brave', 'stone']
text, line = [], []
for word in guess:
    for character in word:
        if character == 'b' or character == 'a':
            color = Fore.RED
        elif character == 's' or character == 'e':
            color = Fore.GREEN
        else:
            color = Fore.BLACK
        line.append(color + character + Fore.RESET)
    text.append(' '.join(line))
    line.clear()
for i in range(1, len(guess) + 1):
    print(*text[:i], sep = '\n')
```

Comment: I think your way might also work, thanks for pointing out clear() method.